# Possible bug in pasting code?

Tags: feature-request, bug

This "bug" actually is general to all Exchanges, I'm asking about it here, since this is the StackExchange most affected by the use of code.

The bug can be reproduced as such :

1. Create a list of hierarchical steps / points by typing "1" like I just did.
2. If you try to paste code into any of these steps, it will not get formatted correctly.

   if (this.text == code) { //if this text is code
   ChangeFormatting(this.text) = code.format;
   }

It may not look like it, but the line above this one has been selected and formatted as code. ([Proof](http://puu.sh/hQmcY/4be90b1ef0.png)).

If I wanted to link code, I'd have to finish the "Step 2.", write a line of text, and then paste it, so it'll be formatted correctly.

```
if (this.text == code) { //if this text is code
    ChangeFormatting(this.text) = code.format;
    }
```

I'm pretty sure it's not as alarming of a bug as any others, but it's something I noticed, and made it a small bit irritating for me to figure out how to correctly paste code. It would be great if this has enough visibility and gets fixed. Thanks!

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99637/158100